# Using socket.io with aurelia

Tags: socket.io, aurelia

I am trying to use socket.io in the framework aurelia. But when I start my server I get

```
error /Users/pierrehedkvist/TDDD272017/picasso/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js
```

I am adding socket.io to my aurelia.json file like this:

```
    "dependencies": [
       ....
      {
         "name": "socket.io-client",
         "path": "../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min"
      }
    ]
```

And I use it like this (app.js). I try to import socket.io-client and test if I can write to the server.

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ApplicationState} from './application-state';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:3000' );
io.emit('chat message', "TESTING");

@inject(ApplicationState)
export class App {
  constructor (appState) {
    this.appState = appState;
    console.log(this.appState);
    //this.appState.test = "Billy";
    this.players = "";
  }

  /*activate() {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('chat message', "TESTING");
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
  }*/

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Piccasso or Not';
    config.map([
      { route: '', moduleId: 'home', nav:true, name: "Home",  title: 'Home'},
      { route: 'game',  name: 'game',
          moduleId: 'control/game',    nav: true, title:'Create a game' },
      { route: 'draw',  name: 'draw',
          moduleId: 'control/draw',    nav: true, title:'Draw something' },
      { route: 'theme',  name: 'theme',
          moduleId: 'theme',    nav: true, title:'Theme' },
      { route: 'next-player',  name: 'next-player',
          moduleId: 'control/next-player',    nav: true, title:'Next player' },
      { route: 'guess', name: 'guess',
          moduleId: 'control/guess', nav:true, title: 'Guess'}
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }

  activate() {
    this.message = 'Hellow world';
  }

  joinGame() {
    console.log("Join lobby " + this.lobbyID)
  }

  createGame() {
    console.log("createGame")
  }
}
```

EDIT:

So I found out my path was incorrect, it now is this.

```
    "name": "socket.io-client",
    "path": "../node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.min"
```

Then in app.js I put:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:3000' );
//io.emit('chat message', "TESTING");
```

and made a function called test() which is called from a button which successfully sends a message to my server.

```
  test() {
    socket.emit('chat message', "testing");
  }
```

Comment: Can you copy in all of your code for the file where you're doing the `import io from 'socket.io-client'`?

Comment: Just made the edit

Comment: What happens if you move `var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:3000' );
io.emit('chat message', "TESTING");` into your `constructor()` method?

Comment: It didnt work from the constructor but I managed to make a function which can send messages to the socket. See my edit, thx :)